# use_required_attribute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'initial' django forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I wrote a dynamic form:

```
class VoteForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        question = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if question:
            if question.allow_multiple_votes:
                choice_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=question.choice_set)
            else:
                choice_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=question.choice_set)
            choice_field.widget = forms.RadioSelect
            choice_field.label=False
            choice_field.empty_label=None
            choice_field.error_messages={'required': _('No choice selected.'),
                                         'invalid': _('Invalid choice selected.')}
            self.fields['choice'] = choice_field
```

Without the RadioSelect widget everything seems to work, but with it, the following error occurs:

> TypeError: use_required_attribute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'initial'

Comment: What about if you set `choice_field.initial = "some_value"`?

Answer (score 6):

When you set the widget after having created the field, it must be a widget instance, not the class itself. But you have to set choices yourself:

```
   choice_field.widget = forms.RadioSelect(choices=...)
```

Preferably, you can give the widget class when you construct your field:

```
   choice_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=question.choice_set, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you have (assuming a typo) error in your widget declaration. You need an instance of the `RadioSelect` class as a widget:

```
choice_field.widget = forms.RadioSelect()
```

Then you can set the `initial` value manually.
You can choose one of two options to do that:

**Option 1:**

Set `initial` at form instantiation:

```
if question.allow_multiple_votes:
            choice_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=question.choice_set,
                initial=0 
            )       
        else:
            choice_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=question.choice_set
                initial=0
            )
```

**Option 2:**

Set the `initial` attribute: `choice_field.initial=0` (as @nik_m points out in the comments)

---

With `initial=0` the first item of the queryset will be selected.